# What should be the definition of absurdity?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-mathematics, terminology

I several times have encountered questions, asked by myself and other people about different things, subjects, phenomena, considered to be absurd to common perception. But, sometimes through rigourous thinking, I have found some valiant insight into wisdom by answering those questions(some).

History says absurdity is often misunderstood. Before Gallileo's obsrvation of the solar system, the idea of a heliocentric solar system would have seemed absurd. Set theory's some assertions seem to be absurd to common sense. Einstein's thinking beyond Newtonian gravity seemed absurd. Sometimes 'absurd' thinking gives birth to new realm of wisdom.

So, my question, what should be the exact definition of 'absurdity?

Comment: It is a term for how we cannot find answers yet keep asking them.

Comment: And sometimes that effort opens countless new windows of wisdom.

Comment: As you can see, [Absurdity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absurdity) is a key concept in many different fields; thus, a "core" definition is quite hard, if not impossible. Compare e.g. [Absurdism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absurdism) and [Existentialism and the Absurd](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/existentialism/#AnxNotAbs) with [Logic: Reductio ad absurdum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductio_ad_absurdum) and [Dialetheism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/dialetheism/).

Comment: Alsoo @Mockingbird what about the Wittgensteinian aphorism: the world of the rich man is different from the world of the poor man?

Comment: Absurd has its root in a words implying one literally lacks a sense ('deaf' or 'unconscious', perhaps before that 'making noises like the wind'.)  So part of the definition should have more to do with the lack of sense than with falseness.  The Absurd in art is not about fallacy or impossibility so much as about disconnection to the point that no logic can be applied.

Comment: Absurdity is trying to divest yourself of the errors and mistakes of a past which haunts you while continuing to commit the same errors in the present.

Comment: The "absurdist monthly review" says "No one has come up with a compact, concrete description similar to surrealism's dream metaphor; so, I will try:
"Absurdism expresses the meaninglessness of life whose only beauty is self-contradiction."" but it is not a reliable source

Comment: Absurdity is the illogical amidst the commonplace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absurdity is self-contradiction. Absurdity is the situation when one set of premises, or one set of observations, requires a conclusion that must be true and must be false at the same time.